# MongoDB How to compare fields in a single document?

Tags: mongodb

Given the collection "example":

```
{_id: 1, prediction: "H", result: "A"}
{_id: 2, prediction: "H", result: "H"}
{_id: 3, prediction: "A", result: "A"}
```

What do I need to do to find records where the prediction and result values match?  ie. documents 2 and 3?

Finding all the "H" predictions is:

```
db.example.find( { prediction: "H" } )
```

But I need to replace the literal "H" with the value in the result field of the same document.

Edit: Sorry, I should have said that I was using Mongo 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use agregation

```
    db.example.aggregate(
       [
         {
           $project:
              {
                _id: 1,
                prediction: 1,
                result: 1,
                compare: { $eq: [ "$prediction", "$result" ] }
              }
         },
         {
           $match:
              {
                compare: true
              }
         }
       ]
    )
```

Comment: This is very similar to another solution I found:
db.example.find( { $expr: { $eq: ["$prediction", "$result"] } } ).  I like these answers because they're efficient and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with an aggregation query, try out the `$redact` stage:

```
db.test.aggregate(
   [
     { $redact: {
        $cond: {
           if: { $eq: [ "$prediction", "$result" ] },
           then: "$$DESCEND",
           else: "$$PRUNE"
         }
       }
     }
   ]
);
```

This will yield the result:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "prediction" : "H", "result" : "H" }
{ "_id" : 3, "prediction" : "A", "result" : "A" }
```

More info on redact can be found here - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#redact-aggregation

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 3.6, this will work. [refer this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/index.html)

```
db.getCollection('TEST').find( { $where: function() {
   return this.prediction == this.result
} })
```

**Result** :

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "prediction" : "H",
    "result" : "H"
}
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "prediction" : "A",
    "result" : "A"
}
```

Comment: It's advised to not use $where unless it's something that the aggregation pipeline doesn't support, as it will require the server to spin up the JavaScript engine to process the data.

Comment: @KevinSmith Thank you, I was not aware of that.

Comment: However, this reminded me of a better way to do this!